# The requested sku is not assigned to given stock. Product is not displayed

Tags: magento2, product, magento2.3, msi

When I go to product page I get this: 
The requested sku is not assigned to given stock.

Also product is not displayed on category page.
[image: o]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured it out right after posting here.

On product listing check products and in the action menu select to assign to sources.

EDIT

just to make it a bit clearer;

Backend -> product grid -> select the products and from the "Actions" drop-down on top of the products grid select "**Assign Inventory Source**"
;)

Comment: you made my day.  AWESOME!!

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: I have multiple sources, what would clicking on "Assign Inventory Source" do?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that the stock was not assigned to website.

STORES > STOCKS > (Assing stock to website/sales channel)