# The requested sku is not assigned to given stock...except it is

Tags: magento2, rest-api

Let me start by saying I'm completely new to Magento. I also *hate* Magento with the burning passion of 1000 suns. So if I've misunderstood something, please bear with me.

I'm using Magento 2's "REST" API (against my will).
I can create products, attributes, attribute sets, etc. just fine...but when I visit the URL of my newly created product, I see `The requested sku is not assigned to given stock`

I found [this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/305043/the-requested-sku-is-not-assigned-to-given-stock-product-is-not-displayed) whose answer appears to be suggesting that assigning a source will resolve this....however, in the image below you will see I clearly have a source selected/assigned.

[image]

Have I misunderstood something? I'm going to guess that's the case, since their documentation more closely resembles a spilled can of Alphabet Soup than any useful, informative, coherent documentation. I mean really....I'm mostly just *guessing* with what I send in my API calls at this point.

Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this? I'm 3 weeks behind schedule because Magento.

Please let me know if you require any additional information from me.

Thanks

Comment: There are api calls to set stock at source level. Its unclear if you have tried this. https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/333570/70343 try setting a default stock.